# How to remove all files from dropzone after uploading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dropzone.js

I have created a dropzone  using  [ng-dropzone](https://github.com/thatisuday/ng-dropzone)

```
  myApp.config(function(dropzoneOpsProvider) {
  dropzoneOpsProvider.setOptions({
    url: 'url',
    acceptedFiles: 'image/jpeg, images/jpg, image/png',
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictDefaultMessage: 'Click to add or drop photos',
    dictRemoveFile: 'Remove photo',
    dictResponseError: 'Could not upload this photo',
    maxFilesize: 100,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 5,
    maxFiles: 10
   });
});

myApp.controller('topStoryController',
    $scope.dzOptions = {
        paramName: 'file',
        maxFilesize: '10'
    }; $scope.dzCallbacks = {
        'successmultiple': function(file, xhr) {
            console.log('uploaded ' + file.name);
            console.log(file, xhr);
            console.log(xhr.path);
        },
    };


    $scope.post = function() {

    }
```

);
Here I am uploading multiple image using dropzone that is working properly
after imaaging upload on post I want to remove images from dropzone.

how to achive this?

Answer (score 3):

dropzone has the following function for removing all files.

```
removeAllFiles();
```

[documentation of dropzone](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#dropzone-methods) explains this function as following

> If you want to remove all files, simply use .removeAllFiles(). Files
>   that are in the process of being uploaded won’t be removed. If you
>   want files that are currently uploading to be canceled, call
>   .removeAllFiles(true) which will cancel the uploads.

[documentation of the ng-dropzone](https://github.com/thatisuday/ng-dropzone) directive states that you can access dropzone functions using the following

```
$scope.dzMethods.removeFile(file);
```

or

```
<button ng-click="dzMethods.removeAllFiles();">...</button>
```